# Making an object move through another and keep going?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently making a sidescrolling game in Unity 2D where an enemy rises up, and then dives down to the player, but then keeps going until it is off screen, like how this image shows. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmB8a.png) I can get the enemy to collide with the player but I can't make it keeping in that direction until off screen. How would I be able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your collider to trigger (it's a checkbox on your collider)

[image: trigger]

That means your object will not be affected by physics when it touch another collider, but it can calls functions.

You have to replace OnCollisionEnter/OnCollisionEnter2D, etc by OnTriggerEnter/OnTriggerEnter2D, etc.

Be careful, the parameter of the function may change too (Collision/Collider).